# The return type 'Null' isn't a 'String', as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a TextFormField template. the function takes multiple arguments from the UI, here is the function:

```
TextFormField _buildRoundedTextField(
    String label,
    TextEditingController controller, {
    TextInputType? keyboardType,
    bool isPassword = false,
    String Function(String)? validationState, 
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
      controller: controller,
      keyboardType: keyboardType,
      obscureText: isPassword,
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: label,
        filled: true,
        fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
        border: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
        ),
      ),
      validator: validatorState
        return null;
      },
    );
  }
```

the issue appears when i pass the validator through the function as follows:

```
_buildRoundedTextField('Family Name', familyNameController,
                validationState: (value) {
              String pattern = r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$';
              RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
              if (!regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
                return 'Enter a valid email';
              }
              return null;
            }),
```

it won't return null and i'm not sure what string to return instead.

Comment: are you copying right the code? what is validatorState? this code is wrong

validator: validatorState
        return null;
      },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code , i made some changes

- `validationState` type changed into  `FormFieldValidator<String>?`
- added a new variable `AutovalidateMode`

Widget :

```
  TextFormField _buildRoundedTextField(
    String label,
    TextEditingController controller, {
    TextInputType? keyboardType,
    bool isPassword = false,
    AutovalidateMode validationMode = AutovalidateMode.disabled,
    FormFieldValidator<String>? validationState,
  }) {
    return TextFormField(
        controller: controller,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        obscureText: isPassword,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          labelText: label,
          filled: true,
          fillColor: Colors.grey[200],
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          ),
        ),
        autovalidateMode: validationMode,
        validator: validationState);
  }
```

Widget implementation :

```
Center(
    child: _buildRoundedTextField('Family Name', familyNameController,
        validationMode: AutovalidateMode.onUserInteraction,
        validationState: (value) {
      String pattern = r'^[\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4}$';
      RegExp regExp = RegExp(pattern);
      if (value != null && !regExp.hasMatch(value)) {
        return 'Enter a valid email';
      }
      return null;
    }),
  ),
```

result :

[image]

[image]